# Connecting R to Osisoft Pi Historian

Tags: r, rodbc, osisoft

I'm trying to connect R to Osisoft Pi Historian with no success. Has anyone done this before or is there a package I can install?

This simple script doesn't return any connections, I haven't used RODBC so could be way off track, thanks for any suggestions.

```
library(RODBC)
x <- odbcDataSources()
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the OSIsoft PI ODBC driver installed on your system?

Have you checked out OSIsofts own whitepaper
[Integrating the PI System with R](https://pisquare.osisoft.com/docs/DOC-2253-white-paper-integrating-the-pi-system-with-r)

Im assuming you are using R Console only? in which case there are examples in the bottom of the article.

I previously used R Dot Net and the AF SDK to process PI data in R,

Many ways to skin the cat...